# Is it possible to use Git with ABAP repository?

Tags: git, eclipse, abap

My current workflow is...

1. Pull code base into Brackets IDE from Bitbucket (Git).
2. Make changes in Brackets.
3. Link Eclipse workspace (same location as Brackets) to ABAP repository using the ABAP plugin.
4. Push changes to SAP using ABAP plugin in Eclipse.
5. Push changes to Git in Brackets.

Is there any way the Eclipse can link to Git and ABAP at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why this got downvoted because there is a solution to this problem.

In a CI environment you can add the following package to your grunt task:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-nwabap-ui5uploader

This will integrate the deployment of your UI5 sources into your grunt task chain. You need some kind of build server to do this. We use a Team Foundation Server with TFBuild. Everytime a pull request is successful, a grunt task is executed which builds (minifies etc.) the application and deploys it to SAP

---

Edit: I never worked with Bitbucket, but it seems like Bamboo is something similar to TFBuild

Answer (score 1):

For future visitors:

[abapGit](https://docs.abapgit.org/) exists at least since 2016 and is available for all ABAP releases after 702 version. It provides most of the Git functionality.

[image]